# How to pass argument to add_action while the method is inside a class?

Tags: php, actions

in my `functions.php` I have

```
require 'autoloader.php';
add_action('init', 'MyClass::make');
```

and in my `MyClass` class I have

```php
class MyClass {
    public static function make($type) {
        var_dump($type);die;
    }
}
```

but the output of `var_dump` is `string(0) ""`. What I want is to pass the argument to this class as `$type`. What I tried was to pass it through `do_action` however I think it is not best practice.

How can I pass argument to a method which is inside a class for `add_action`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example on how you could implement the `add_action`:

```php
$type = 'my_sample_type';

add_action(
    'init',
    function() use ( $type ) {
        MyClass::make( $type );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `init` hook doesn't pass any parameters - when you call `add_action`, `init` isn't passing anything to `make`.

You could just call `make` outright:

```php
require 'autoloader.php';
MyClass::make( <whatever );
```

If you need to do this on `init`, set up a callback function:

```php
function add_my_type() {
    MyClass::make( <foo> );
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_my_type' );
```

Comment: `init` was as an example, what I tried on, was `add_meta_boxes`. What you mentioned is creating a function and inside that to call a method of a class. So what is the usage of that class. We make class in order not to have these kinds on functions.